# Adding a new "Stock Market" or "Economy" site

Tags: feature-request

I've been looking for a stack where I can ask questions regarding the stock market and other recent happenings in the economy like how will Brexit affect the economy.

A new site regarding this type of themes will be of great use to many people.

Answer (score 0):

There's already something called [Economy](http://economics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Was it really necessary to add an animated gif to convey this information?

Comment: @Chris That was a good illustration on searching for stacks altogether.